# Android JSON Parsing string cannot ne converted to jsonobject

Tags: android, json, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I'm trying to Parse this JSON From this URL

[https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/sjm6mdaoghv5kipc2p80jrgsc0%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic?alt=json](https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/sjm6mdaoghv5kipc2p80jrgsc0@group.calendar.google.com/public/basic?alt=json)

if i try to parse this url getting

Exception:

```
    10-09 12:34:31.216: W/System.err(1856): org.json.JSONException: Value Response of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
10-09 12:34:31.376: W/System.err(1856):     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
10-09 12:34:31.391: W/System.err(1856):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
10-09 12:34:31.546: W/System.err(1856):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
10-09 12:34:31.701: W/System.err(1856):     at com.example.googlecalenderevents.MainActivity2$DownloadXmlTask.doInBackground(MainActivity2.java:99)
10-09 12:34:31.854: W/System.err(1856):     at com.example.googlecalenderevents.MainActivity2$DownloadXmlTask.doInBackground(MainActivity2.java:1)
10-09 12:34:32.031: W/System.err(1856):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-09 12:34:32.192: W/System.err(1856):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
10-09 12:34:32.201: W/System.err(1856):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-09 12:34:32.363: W/System.err(1856):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
10-09 12:34:32.381: W/System.err(1856):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
10-09 12:34:32.390: W/System.err(1856):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Here is my Code:

```
public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {




    static InputStream is = null;
String json;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new DownloadXmlTask().execute();



    }
    private class DownloadXmlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONArray> {
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... urls) {

            // Making HTTP request
            try {
                Log.d("doInBackground", "doInBackground");

                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/sjm6mdaoghv5kipc2p80jrgsc0%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic?alt=json");


                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                json = sb.toString();

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }
            try {

                //JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);

                JSONArray array=new JSONArray(json);




                Log.d("ffsf","fsfs");

                }


            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
            // Accessing your data



        }




    }
}
```

Could any one help?

Comment: post the content of the server response

Answer (score 2):

You do not have a JSONArray. Google Returns a JSON Object (see there are not Array Brackets [] around it)
So try :

```
   JSONObject array=new JSONObject(json);
```

For example the "link" in your JSON is an Array

```
link: [
  {
    rel: "alternate",
    type: "text/html",
    href: "https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?  src=sjm6mdaoghv5kipc2p80jrgsc0%40group.calendar.google.com"
  },
  {
...
  },
 ....
],
```

and maybe remove the + `"\n"` from `sb.append(line + "\n")`;

Maybe you should try not `https://` try it with `http://`

Comment: If i do  JSONObject array=new JSONObject(json); also getting same exception

Comment: Try a Log.d("JSON", json);

Comment: and maybe remove the + "\n" from  sb.append(line + "\n");

Comment: I have tried  Log.d("JSON", json); getting Response contains no content type

Comment: So you do not have a json string in your json.

Comment: Yeah but perhaps your app does not handle "SSL" https

Comment: Try To log the status code after you made the response with Log.d("RESPONSE CODE", "" + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

Comment: Try To log the status code after you made the response with Log.d("RESPONSE CODE", "" + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

Comment: And do you get a stackTrace from your catches before?

Comment: And do you get a stackTrace from your catches before?

Comment: and maybe remove the + "\n" from sb.append(line + "\n");

Comment: I've update stacktrace in my question ann tried remove the + "\n" from sb.append(line + "\n") also getting same Exception